# Pipe+directive in Angular 2 with ES5: No Directive annotation found on constructor

Tags: angular

I have a very simple pipe:

```
app.DisplayKeystrokePipe = ng.core
    .Pipe({
        name: "displayKeystroke"
    })
    .Class({
        transform: function() {

        }
    });
```

and a more complex component/directive:

```
app.DropDownCmp = ng.core
    .Component({
        selector: "dropdown",
        templateUrl: "dropdown.html",
        inputs: [
            'list',
            'selected'
        ],
        outputs: [
            'selectedChange'
        ]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function() {
            this.selectedChange = new ng.core.EventEmitter();
            this.display = "Hello";
            this.onClickHandler = function(event) {
                if(this.listVisible && !$(event.target).is(".dropdown-display") && !$(event.target).parents(".dropdown-display").length > 0) {
                    this.listVisible = false;
                }
            }.bind(this);
        },
        isSelected: function(id) {
            return id == this.selected;
        },
        show: function() {
            this.listVisible = true;
        },
        select: function(id) {
            this.selected = id;
            this.selectedChange.next(id);
        },
        ngOnInit: function() {
            document.addEventListener('click', this.onClickHandler)
        },
        ngOnDestroy: function() {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.onClickHandler);
        },
        ngOnChanges: function(changes) {
            this.display = this.list[this.selected];
        },
    });
```

Now I'm trying to use both of these things in one template:

```
app.SomeComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
        template: `<dropdown [list]="someList" [(selected)]="currentEntry"></dropdown><br>{{1 | displayKeystroke}}`,
        directives: [app.DropDownCmp],
        pipes: [app.DisplayKeystrokePipe]
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: [ng.router.RouteData, app.LinkService, function(rd, service) {
            service.setPath(rd.data.catName, rd.data.name);
            this.someList = ['Entry1', 'Entry2', 'Entry3'];
            this.currentEntry = 0;
        }]
    });
```

However, I get the error message: `EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on constructor`

When I only use the directive in the template though, it works:

```
template: `<dropdown [list]="someList" [(selected)]="currentEntry"></dropdown>`
```

Same when I only use the pipe:

```
template: `{{1 | displayKeystroke}}`
```

Only when I use both at the same time I get this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/A0hnvvVC6oxZBqIE38Eu?p=preview

Comment: I don't have all your code, so I reduced it to the minimum in this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/oJVjWdgd27iBVGVfOEKV?p=preview) and it's working fine. Use that same plnkr, fork it and then share it when you can reproduce your error.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/A0hnvvVC6oxZBqIE38Eu?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the problem, in your pipe you have this line

```
constructor: function constructor() {}
```

That line makes it fail, how and why? Sadly I can't tell for sure. But if you change it to match the class name, or simply using `function() {}` works fine.

```js
app.DisplayKeystrokePipe = ng.core.Pipe({
    name: "displayKeystroke"
}).Class({

    // Match class name
    constructor: function DisplayKeystrokePipe () {},

    // or simply using function() {}
    //constructor: function() {},

    transform: function() {
        return "FIRED";
    }
});
```

Weirdly enough this doesn't happen with the Directive that also has `constructor: function constructor() {}`. So I would simply stick to `constructor: function() {}` to avoid problems.

Here's your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/66xEaQXjVlyvTWgllrWF?p=preview) working.

Comment: I see the problem. I never wrote `function constructor() {}` but Babelify did this for me. I have no idea why. using `function DisplayKeystrokePipe () {},` works even through babelification, so thanks for that!

Comment: Oh, look at that! Thanks for the tip about babel (I don't use it, but it's useful to know it). You're welcome and  thanks to you too!